# Trouble with SIM808 shield

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I've been trying to work with Waveshare SIM 808 shield on arduino, quite similar to this one:
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/GSM/GPRS/GPS_Shield_(B)#How_to_use_with_Arduino_UNO_R3

I tried using multiple examples, such as this:

```
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>


#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&Serial);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //******** Initialize sim808 module *************
  while(!sim808.init()) { 
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
  }  

  //************* Turn on the GPS power************
  if( sim808.attachGPS())
      Serial.println("Open the GPS power success");
  else 
  Serial.println("Open the GPS power failure");

}

void loop() {
    //************** Get GPS data *******************
    if (sim808.getGPS()) {
    Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.year);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.month);
Serial.print("/");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.day);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.hour);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.minute);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(sim808.GPSdata.second);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.centisecond);

Serial.print("latitude :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lat,6);

sim808.latitudeConverToDMS();
Serial.print("latitude :");
Serial.print(sim808.latDMS.degrees);
Serial.print("\^");
Serial.print(sim808.latDMS.minutes);
Serial.print("\'");
Serial.print(sim808.latDMS.seconeds,6);
Serial.println("\"");
Serial.print("longitude :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.lon,6);
sim808.LongitudeConverToDMS();
Serial.print("longitude :");
Serial.print(sim808.longDMS.degrees);
Serial.print("\^");
Serial.print(sim808.longDMS.minutes);
Serial.print("\'");
Serial.print(sim808.longDMS.seconeds,6);
Serial.println("\"");

Serial.print("speed_kph :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.speed_kph);
Serial.print("heading :");
Serial.println(sim808.GPSdata.heading);

//************* Turn off the GPS power ************
sim808.detachGPS();
  }

}
```

or this

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX
String comdata = "";
void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

 while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  delay(200);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  delay(2000);
   mySerial.println("AT");   
   delay(200);
   //Send message
   mySerial.println("AT+CGNSPWR=1");
   delay(200);
   //reset GPS in autonomy mode
   mySerial.println("AT+CGNSTST=1");
   delay(200);
   mySerial.listen();
   while(1)
  {  
    while(mySerial.available()>0)  
        Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    while(Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());  
  } 
}
```

### In first case, I obviously don't declare RX, TX pins and use the Arduino's general purpose RX, TX pins (0, 1).

In second case I used wires to connect Arduino pins 2 and 3, to shield's D0 and D1 pins.

In both cases, neither RX or TX leds on shield's module light up, which means that it doesn't receive the sent data.

I made sure to set UART/ARDUINO switch on ARDUINO position and I did reset the module several times.

I am using Arduino Uno. What goes wrong here?

Comment: try this ... https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialPassthrough

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand, Serial1 is not declared on Arduino Uno board. Am I supposed to declare it myself? @jsotola

Comment: sorry, i was not paying attention to the content of the link ... use that sketch, but change Serial1 to be software serial ... that way you can use the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE to talk to the SIM808 ... then type the AT commands in the serial monitor window, or use a serial terminal program, such as Putty

Comment: I have no trouble using the shield, while connected directly to it via micro USB and sending AT commands using Putty. Howevery, once I connect to Arduino board and connect shield to Arduino it just won't work. I tried replacing Serial1 with Serial and typing AT commands in Arduino Serial Monitor, but I doesn't send any reply

Comment: make Serial1 software serial that is connected to the SIM808

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thank you so much

Comment: the sketch is similar to your second sketch except that it uses `if` statements ... the `while` statements in your sketch block execution until all data is received on one of the serial ports ... the `if` statements allow the code to service the serial ports in an alternating fashion